# Insert data into avro-formatted, partitioned hive table with data from HDFS

Tags: apache-hive

I have created a hive table named employee (avro formatted) with partition on department.

I have the avro dataset in my HDFS location. My dataset is also having department id.

I would like to import the data into Hive table with the data from HDFS. During the import, I want the data to be kept in its respective partition.

How to achieve this? any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing it.

1.`Manual partitioning`

load data inpath `hdfs path` into table employee_table partition(deptId='1')

load data inpath `hdfs path` into table employee_table partition(deptId='2')

2.`Dynamic partitioning`

a. Create a intermediate table

b. Create a employee table with partition

c. Load data from intermediate table to partition table

Comment: Thanks @shankarsh15. 

By using Manual Partitioning, data in HDFS must be organized according to the target partition I wish to create isn't it? Otherwise, all the data in the HDFS path may be stored in one partition.. am I right?